# How to stop a java 8 lambda-runnable-thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I would like to stop this thread:

```
Runnable run = () -> { while(true)[...]; };
run.run();
```

But there is no `run.stop()` method.

Please suggest either an other as short as possible method to start and stop a thread or a method to stop this running... thing.

Comment: What thread?  I don't see anywhere where you're creating a thread.

Comment: FWIW: Here's a different way of thinking about what others said below:  Thread.start() is the method that the library provides for your code to call to start a thread.  YourClass.run() is the method that _you_ provide for the library to call _in_ the new thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Runnable.run()` does not create a thread. You're invoking the run() method in your current thread. To create a thread you need to do just that: create and start a thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(run);
t.start();
```

Then later on you can invoke

```
t.interrupt();
```

Please read the javadocs on `Thread.interrupt()` on how to structure your `run()` method to be interruptable.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you normally do is to add a volatile boolean field to the runnable that is set by a different thread.

In your case you might perhaps use an AtomicBoolean instead of a volatile field and capture that in the closure. Once the closure is created, you can use this AtomicBoolean to stop.

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop a thread ,first create a thread like this

```
Thread thread = new Thread(run);
```

and in order to start the thread 
call

```
thread.start();
```

The [start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) method will call `run` method but if you call `run()` method directly **then no new thread will be created and** the code will be executed in the existing thread. In order to stop the method you can use [interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())